# What is the main difference between os.Args and os.Stdin?

Tags: go, unix, math

So I have been trying to understand what is the real use of these two functions.
I only understand the fact that Args gets user input as an **slice** and the Stdin as a **string**. So does that mean with Args I can store more values and access them more easily, and with stdin I only get to store at max one input at a time? Can somebody give a simple explanation and practical use of these two function? Thx

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Scan()
result := scanner.Text()
fmt.Println(result)
```

.

```
arguments := os.Args

fmt.Println(arguments[1:])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.Stdin` is the [standard input stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), used for [piping data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) from one program to another or for dynamic user input which can be used to make [text based user interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).

`os.Args` are the arguments passed to the program when calling it. `./prog a b "hello world"` would result in `["prog", "a", "b", "hello world"]`. This is also the mechanism used for [flags](https://pkg.go.dev/flag)

You can use both at the same time.